# Android: How to fire a search intent like press ENTER when using `OnQueryTextListener`?

Tags: android, android-intent, searchview

I want to build a instant searchview, which will show the search result immediately in the same layout as soon as a user input anything. So I am googling and decide to use [onQueryTextChange](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener.html) to implement that. However I cannot figure out how to "fire" a intent like the normal result which pressing ENTER will lead to, to tell my `Activity` that there is an event that a user have input something in searchview and you(`Activity`) should handle it.

Any idea to help?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correcty you want to recognize `KEY_EVENT` (ENTER). I've ended with custom `EditText` styled like original `SearchView`, then used `OnEditorActionListener`:

```
queryEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH ||
                    (event != null && event.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                performSearch();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

`SearchView` don't have `setOnEditorActionListener` method, thats why I'm using simple `EditText`

note `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH` option inside "if", you may request "special" keyboard layout with magnify icon instead of Enter key (but remember that not all keyboards are supporting this option and custom keyboard app may show "usual" layout of keyboard)

```
android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
```